# Calculate polygon intersection without boundary intersections

Tags: r, gis, r-sf, boundary

I'm trying to find intersections between U.S. counties in different years from the shapefiles I downloaded from the NHGIS site.

When I use `st_intersection()` I get a lot of intersections at the boundaries between the counties because the boundaries are not exactly the same between the years.
I tried to use some functions to fix this thing such as:

1. `st_make_valid()`
2. `st_snap()`
3. `st_set_precision()`

But nothing worked (or I did not use the commands correctly).
I also tried to create a small negative buffer and it did work but I am looking for a more elegant solution

Comment: Boundaries are part of the intersection

Comment: It has a function argument, by default for polygons it should not be part of the intersection. But that's not the problem, the problem is that the boundaries are inaccurate from year to year so there are intersections that are not real.

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to tag it with the specific languages and technologies you are using? This will attract attention of people familiar with those technologies.  [tag:gis] and [tag:boundary] are generic tags that are unlikely to attract attention.  I'm guessing your tags should include [tag:postgis] but this is not my area of expertise.  See: [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging).  See also [ask] and the [tour].

Comment: *I also tried to create a small negative buffer and it did work but I am looking for a more elegant solution* -- if you have polygons whose boundaries are imprecise and "noisy" then offsetting them inwards by some accepted tolerance isn't a bad way of ignoring overlaps due to noise.

Comment: Thanks, I added tags I hope now maybe someone can help me. Right, I also wanted to set some tolerance but did not find the way to do it in `st_intersection()` function or any other way. @abc